# Proving a sequence is increasing

Tags: sequences-and-series

Prove the sequence defined by $a_0=1$ and $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{3a_n+4}$ is increasing for all $n\ge0$ and $0\le a_n\le4$

I know that a sequence is increasing if $a_n\le a_{n+1}$ but I don't know what information I can use to prove that since all I have is $a_{n+1}$ and a base case of n=0. Am I able to just test integers 0 to 4 to prove it is true? Or is there another method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As so often with recursive sequences, induction does the trick. First note that $a_0 = 1 \in [0,4]$, and if $a_n \in [0,4]$, we have
$$ a_{n+1} = \sqrt{3a_n + 4} \ge \sqrt 4 \ge 0 $$
and 
$$ a_{n+1} = \sqrt{3a_n + 4} \le \sqrt{3 \cdot 4 + 4} = 4 $$
hence $a_{n+1} \in [0,4]$. Therefore $a_n \in [0,4]$ for all $n$.

To prove that $(a_n)$ is increasing, note that using $4 \ge a_n$ we have
$$ a_{n+1} = \sqrt{3a_n + 4} \ge \sqrt{4a_n} \ge \sqrt{a_n^2} = a_n $$

Comment: $a_{n+1}\ge 0$ because it is the square root of something.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that if $1 < x < 4$, then essentially, $x^2 - 3x + 4 < 0$. Prove by induction that $1 < a_n < 4$. Then, set $x = a_n$ to get that $\{a_n\}$ is increasing.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick sketch, not a complete solution.

Try an induction on $n$ for showing that $0\le a_n\le4$.
This is easy.

Once done, write that $a_{n+1} > a_n$ and try to prove it.
After some trivial rework, it's equivalent to $(a_n+1)(a_n-4) < 0$
which is true (from the induction which you completed).